# Unable to use Intel oneAPI DPCT for migration of my applicaiton: Error Code -5

Tags: intel-oneapi, intel-dpct

I'm attempting to follow the instructions from this site https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-dpcpp-compatibility-tool/top.html. I receive an error when I use the dpct command, stating that the path for CUDA header files is incorrect. Now, in order to add the CUDA path, I must first install the CUDA toolkit, which I am unable to accomplish **without sudo access** and I don't have sudo privilege to my other server. Can someone please help me here.

> dpct exited with code: -5 (Error: Path for CUDA header files is invalid or not available. Use --cuda-include-path to specify the correct path to the header files)

Answer (score 0):

You can install CUDA toolkit in your home directory. You may find the instructions on the Nvidia official webpage that home directory installation doesn't require sudo.

Once you have installed the toolkit, use the below command to perform migration for a single source file as below:

```
dpct --cuda-include-path=/path/to/cuda/include sample.cu
```

Thanks,
Santosh